# import/save SNAP Facebook edges in Apache Giraph

Tags: facebook, data-import, giraph

I'm using SNAP facebook dataset for social network analysis. SNAP uses simple edge list as a data format "node1 node2" . How can I read SNAP dataset in Apache Giraph? I am reading the file with BufferedReader line per line but do not know how to save it in BSP model with adjacency lists. Can someone help me with a **code example in java?** 
I would also like to add information about the nodes (characteristics each user/node has) how can I do that in Giraph?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SNAP facebook dataset directly. In your command instead of using -vif ... use -eif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IntNullTextEdgeInputFormat. This format reads each line as (source_vertex destination_vertex) just like SNAP dataset.

Comment: For command : ./hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph-1.1.0/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -eif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IntNullTextEdgeInputFormat -vip /user/hduser/input/facebook/0.edges -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/shortestpaths -w 1 I get error of IllegalArgument

Comment: use -eip instead of -vip

Comment: ./hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph-1.1.0/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-‌​2.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -eif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IntNullTextEdgeInputFormat -eip /user/hduser/input/facebook/0.edges -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/shortestpaths -w 1

Comment: No vertex input specified. No vertex output specified

Comment: Since in this command you use -eif (edge input format) and -eip (edge input path), the warning no vertex input specified is not important.